# Best way to store data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I' about to build a calculator using Javascript and PHP and im just wondering what the best option would be to store the data. The calculator will be silmilar to http://psdtowp.com/order-now.

I was originally going post all values in a POST method and then store them in the database for later use, would this be viable or is there a better method?

Ahh brilliant, it only needs to be stored for a short while until the user fills out the next page where all corresponding info would be stored in a database...

Thanks

Comment: what kind of data would you like to store?

Comment: Is there some reason why you'd even think about POSTing the data? Javascript is Turing-complete and perfectly capable of performing calculations client-side...

Answer (score 2):

I think for your purposes storing them in a `$_SESSION`/cookie variable would be fine.

In MySQL seems to be overkill and too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

How long do you need to store it for? If indeed just for a single use, go with @ultimatebuster suggestion and use $_SESSION. If you need to access it later, consider either a database solution or even writing to a text file.